# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' with topicName.setText(getTopicName);

Tags: nullpointerexception

it shows an error on this line but i dont know what to do please explain and help

[showing me a nullpoiterexception i dont know how to resolve it im new to this type of null poiterexception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qlSz.png)
 topicName.setText(getTopicName);

MAIN ACTIVITY CODE:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
// total quiz time in minutes
private int totalTimeInMins = 1;

// Timer class object for countdown timer
private Timer quizTimer;
private int seconds = 0; // current countdown seconds

// questions array list
private List<QuestionsList> questionsLists;

// Current questions index position from  questionsLists ArrayList.
private int currentQuestionPosition = 0;

// Options
private AppCompatButton option1, option2, option3, option4;

// next button
private AppCompatButton nextBtn;

// Total questions and main question TextView
private TextView question;
private TextView questions;

// selectedOption's Value. if user not selected any option yet then it is empty by default
private String selectedOptionByUser = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // initialize widgets from activity_main.xml file
    final ImageView backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
    final TextView topicName = findViewById(R.id.topicName);
    final TextView timer = findViewById(R.id.timer);
    question = findViewById(R.id.question);
    questions = findViewById(R.id.questions);
    option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
    option2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
    option3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);
    option4 = findViewById(R.id.option4);
    nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

    // get Topic Name and User Name from StartActivity via Intent
    final String getTopicName = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedTopic");

    // set Topic Name to TextView
    topicName.setText(getTopicName);

    // start quiz countdown timer
    startTimer(timer);

    // get questions from QuestionsBank class according to selectedTopicName and assign to questionsLists ArrayList
    questionsLists = QuestionsBank.getQuestions(getTopicName);
```

it says theres something wrong with line '67' but idk what it is...

this one : topicName.setText(getTopicName);

error messgae says this:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.learnoset.offlinequizapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)

Comment: Please check with debugger the input value at this point. If you still need help please share a reproducible example as code and not as screenshot.

Comment: @Markus i looked into it and i have shared with the code ...can i get some help

Comment: Obviously `topicName` is a null pointer. I.e. `findViewById(R.id.topicName)` some lines above returns null. Can you please check if the referenced view exists in the layout? If you need more help please share your `activity_main.xml`.